# How to use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem in this example?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I have to use the DCT in order to get the value of this limit:

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^n \biggl(\frac{\sin x}{x} \biggr)^n dx$$

If i take $f_n = \bigl(\frac{\sin x}{x} \bigr)^n, \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n =0 $ so it converges, but i can't tell what function to use for the domination.

My thought is that as $|\sin x| \le |x| $, and $\space  \bigl|\left(\frac{\sin x}{x} \right)^n \bigr| \le \space \left|\frac{\sin x}{x} \right|^n $ then $  \space \left|\frac{\sin x}{x} \right|^n \le 1$ but i feel like I'm messing up hard somewhere.

How would you proof that function is dominated?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use DCT, you have to be on the same measure space. So you should view the original integral as $\int_\mathbb{R} (\frac{\sin x}{x})^n 1_{0 \le x \le n} dx$. Let $f_n(x) = (\frac{\sin x}{x})^n 1_{0 \le x \le n}$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $0 \le x \le 1$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ for $x > 1$. Then $|f_n(x)| \le f(x)$ for each $n \ge 2$ and $x \ge 0$. Since $f \in L^1$, we can apply DCT.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i think i see this now!